# showing java version as 8 for jdk 1.7.0_67

Tags: java, windows, java-home

In environment variables I have set the below things:

```
JAVA_VERSION: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67;
```

And added `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the path.

When I run `java -version` in command prompt it is showing `1.8.0_40`, and not `1.7.0_67`. Why is that?

Comment: Why you need this `JAVA_VERSION` environment variable? Just update it to 1.8.0_40 in the same place where you updated the `PATH` variable.

Comment: check your `C:\Windows\System32` there is `java.exe` there and it's version is `1.8`

Comment: You can use the `where` command in the command prompt to find out where exactly Windows is looking for the java command e.g. "where java".

Comment: sorry for typo. JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67; .I tried Path :C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin; like this, but showing java -version as 8

Comment: Getting C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\java.exe for "where java" command. how to remove the first one from system , Is it like manually possible to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in cmd for command :

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
echo %PATH%
```

If JAVA_HOME is not set then set it

```
set JAVA_HOME="<PATH to JAVA_HOME>"
set PATH=%PATH%;<PATH TO JAVA_HOME/bin>
```

Please note that this change is temporary and you have to set it again in every case when you start cmd

For permanently adding JAVA_HOME and Path, please see https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Answer (score 0):

run the command

```
 echo %PATH%
 echo %JAVA_HOME%
 echo %JRE_HOME%
```

Check java 8 path is include in the above path.If not included, Include the java 8 path in that environment variable.